# When to call ReleaseDesignerOutlets when ViewDidUnload does not exist

Tags: xamarin.ios, uistoryboard

When should you call `ReleaseDesignerOutlets` for a custom storyboard UI class when it's not a `UIViewController` and therefore doesn't have a `ViewDidUnload` method?

Fx. I have a custom UITableViewCell class, and want to release my outlets. I can see there is a `protected void Dispose(bool disposing)` method, but can't figure out if overriding this method is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: As fas as I know you don't have to handle the dispose or release of the UITableViewCell. The dispose is already called after the creation of the cell, even if it's still displayed. 
The tableview is automatically releasing cells when there's memory required (if you don't make static assignments) and you can reload existing cells with the method tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("MyCustomCell") in the GetCell method of your UITableViewSource.

Answer (score 1):

In absence of ViewDidUnload I'm releasing my outlets when my view controller is removed from the navigation stack. Which will only work when using a NavigationController or with PresentViewController. Parent will be *null* in that case.

```
public override void DidMoveToParentViewController(UIViewController parent)
{
  base.DidMoveToParentViewController(parent);

  if(parent == null && cleanupOnNavigationStackRemoval)
    Cleanup();
}


protected void Cleanup()
{
  CleanupBindings();

  ReleaseOutlets();
}
```